# Getting the version number after library's name and extension in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

How can I get the version number after a .so file using Bash?

I have obtained the library's full path and extracted the name. Like `libpcap.so.1.1.1`. Now I need to get the version number after `so`; for example:

```
libpcap.so.1.1.1 --> 1.1.1
libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4 --> 4.4.4
libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT --> 1.8.0
```

Edit: A sample code using grep can handle the first two examples. But not the third.

```
grep -Eo '[0-9][^[:alpha:]]+$' <<<'libpcap.so.1.5.3'
```

Comment: Do you want to scrape a known library's path / filename in order to print the version number or how should the library be identified in first place?

Comment: I have obtained the library full path and extracted the name. Like libpcap.so.1.1.1. Now I need to get the version number after so

Comment: Is the name stored in a file? Are there more than one names? Or is the printed as the result of a command?

Comment: @kos: I guess the question is clear enough and needs no more explanations! I added a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't guarantee that it will catch every corner case, but how about

```
grep -Po '\.so\.\K([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+'
```

- match and discard literal `.so.` on the left (using the PCRE `\K` modifier)
- match zero or more occurrences of one or more digits followed by `.`
- match one or more digits

Note that we don't want to anchor it to the end of the string (`$`) as your original expression does, to allow for a trailing string such as `-PRE-GIT`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'.so.' '{match($2,/([0-9]+\.*)+/);print substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}
```

---

*Examples*

```
$ awk -F'.so.' '{match($2,/([0-9]+\.*)+/);print substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' <<<'libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT1'
1.8.0

$ awk -F'.so.' '{match($2,/([0-9]+\.*)+/);print substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' <<<$'libpcap.so.1.1.1\nlibusb-0.1.so.4.4.4\nlibpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT' 
1.1.1
4.4.4
1.8.0
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for the examples you provided, and will work as long as the input string follows the pattern `.*\.so\.[0-9.]*.*`:

```
grep -Po '.*\.so.\K[0-9.]*' <<<'libpcap.so.1.1.1'
```

It will match the widest possible sequence of digits / dots after the last `.so.` substring, if any.

```
% grep -Po '.*\.so.\K[0-9.]*' <<<$'libpcap.so.1.1.1\nlibusb-0.1.so.4.4.4\nlibpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT'
1.1.1
4.4.4
1.8.0
```